# Did Jack resort to cannibalism?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-mans-chest

In *Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest*, Jack Sparrow — *Captain Jack Sparrow* — flees to land and ends up with the Pelegostos, who make him his chief, which was nice.

When Will Turner comes along, the size of the crew of the *Black Pearl* has shrunken somewhat. The Pelegostos seem to be cannibals. Jack is their chief.

We see <del>Captain</del> *Chief* Jack Sparrow nibble on a toe.

[image: Jack nibbles on a toe]

**Did Jack eat more than just a toe?**

Has he resorted to cannibalism?

---

This [has been asked over on *Movies & TV*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2156/9382), but without a definite answer.

Comment: [Did Captain Jack Sparrow eat people?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2156/44222) on Movies, with no definitive answer.

Comment: Ah, Movies and TV, the older, more on topic brother of this site.

Comment: I don't think he was nibbling on the toe. Just biting the toe nail, because he was nervous. Wasn't it just Jack that they wanted to eat? And they only wanted to do so because he was their chief.